# How to add S3 trigger event on AWS Lambda function using Serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I want to add trigger event on a Lambda function on an **already existing bucket** and for that I am using below configuration:

```
 events:
      - s3:
          bucket: serverlesstest
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: uploads/
            - suffix: .pdf
```

where bucket `serverlesstest` is already existing on S3.

This configurations is throwing the error:

> An error occurred while provisioning your stack: S3BucketServerlesstest - serverlesstest already exists.

How can I resolve this error using Serverless Framework?

Answer (score 13):

It’s not currently possible in the core framework because of CloudFormation behavior. maybe.

But you can use this plugin.

https://github.com/matt-filion/serverless-external-s3-event

After installing serverless-plugin-existing-s3 by `npm install serverless-plugin-existing-s3`.

And add plugins to serverless.yml

```
plugins:
  serverless-plugin-existing-s3
```

Give your deploy permission to access the bucket.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  iamRoleStatements:
    ...
    -  Effect: "Allow"
       Action:
         - "s3:PutBucketNotification"
       Resource:
         Fn::Join:
           - ""
       - - "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME or *"
```

And use `existingS3` event, it is not just `s3`.

```
functions:
  someFunction:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - existingS3:
          bucket: BUCKET_NAME
          events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: images/
            - suffix: .jpg
```

After `sls deploy` command,
You can attach event by using `sls s3deploy` command.

### Feature Proposal

it will be added someday in the future.

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4241

Comment: NOTE: This property was added in version 1.47.0. Older versions don't support this feature. (source: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3#using-existing-buckets)

Answer (score 12):

This is possible as of serverless version v1.47.0, by adding the `existing: true` flag to your event configuration: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/

example from the source:

```
functions:
  users:
    handler: users.handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: legacy-photos
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: uploads/
            - suffix: .jpg
          existing: true # <- this makes it work with existing objects
```

The source provides the following caveats:

> IMPORTANT: You can only attach 1 existing S3 bucket per function.
>
> NOTE: Using the existing config will add an additional Lambda function and IAM Role to your stack. The Lambda function backs-up the Custom S3 Resource which is used to support existing S3 buckets.

Comment: It does nothing. I'm on Serverless 1.5.0 and it completely ignore this property. I literally copy-pasted the code from the docs with a few renames. Completely broken feature.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on 1.58.0 (latest at the time of writing). I had to manually create the event trigger. I really wished this would work...

Comment: @DemonGyro @garryp Note that this functionality creates an additional lambda function `yourservicenameandstage-custom-resource-existing-s3`. If this additional lambda function is not created try checking the indentation of parameters in `- s3` tag. Note that parameters have 4 spaces instead of 2 spaces after the parent tag. I had a similar problem and this fixed it for me so hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have decided to handle things a little differently, so I don't need this functionality anymore, but I will definitely keep the spacing in mind later if I try this again.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you can't specify an existing S3 bucket to trigger the Lambda function because the Serverless Framework* can't change existing infrastructure using Cloud Formation. This configuration requires that you create a **new** bucket.

You can read more in the following issues that were open on GitHub:

- [Can't subscribe to events of existing S3 bucket](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2154)
- [s3 events can't refer to existing bucket](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3257)

<sup>* I would try to configure this trigger using AWS Console or the SDK instead of the Serverelss Framework.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

If the bucket was created using Serverless elsewhere in the stack, then you could use

`- s3:
    Bucket: { Ref: serverlesstest }`

Otherwise you'll have to construct the name or ARN yourself.

Comment: Now I can able to upload function successfully but trigger event still missing  on Lambda function.

Answer (score 3):

`serverless.yml` seems to be very sensitive to spaces. For me [this](https://forum.serverless.com/t/s3-trigger-is-not-registered-after-deployment/1858/4) advice was helpful.

If config looks like this

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.main
    events:
      - s3: 
        bucket: codepipeline-us-east-1-213458767560
        event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
        rules:
          - prefix: test/MyAppBuild
```

you need to add 2 more spaces to the indent of bucket, event & rules:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.main
    events:
      - s3: 
          bucket: codepipeline-us-east-1-213458767560
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: test/MyAppBuild
```