# Event trigger using serverless framwork on an existing S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I'm trying to set a lambda to trigger when an object is created in an S3 bucket.

My serverless.yml includes this:

```
  handleNewRawObjectInS3:
    handler: lambdas/handleNewRawObjectInS3/handleNewRawObjectInS3.handleS3Event
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${file(../evn.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.json):RAW_IMAGE_BUCKET}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

This results in an error:

```
Error:
CREATE_FAILED: S3Bucketxxxxxxxxxrawimages (AWS::S3::Bucket)
xxxxxxxxx-raw-images already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:xxxx:stack/s3-xxxxxxxxx-raw-images/310e7010-xxx-xxx-xxxx-12f066874c93
```

I already have the bucket created -- created via uploading a cloudformation template directly (our corporate version of AWS doesn't allow us to use serverless framework to create a bucket).  [How to add S3 trigger event on AWS Lambda function using Serverless framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818114/how-to-add-s3-trigger-event-on-aws-lambda-function-using-serverless-framework) indicates this was not possible with older versions of serverless, but following the rabbit hole, you can see a feature request ... and later an answer that shows you need to add 'existing: true'.

So I add that to my serverless framework setup:

```
service: my-service-events

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: ${file(../evn.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.json):REGION}
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

  deploymentBucket: #must name manually-created bucket for deployment because enterprise doesn't allow automated bucket creation
    name: ${file(../evn.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.json):DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET}
  iam: #must name a role because enterprise doesn't allow automated role creation
    role: myServerlessRole  # This is a reference to the resource name from the role created in the resources -> iam roles section
    deploymentRole:  ${file(../evn.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.json):DEPLOYMENT_ROLE}
resources:
  - ${file(../iam-roles.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.yml)}

functions:
  handleNewRawObjectInS3:
    handler: lambdas/handleNewRawObjectInS3/handleNewRawObjectInS3.handleS3Event
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${file(../evn.${opt:stage, 'dev'}.json):RAW_IMAGE_BUCKET}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          existing: true
```

The IAM file/role referenced above looks like this:

```
Resources:
  myServerlessRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      PermissionsBoundary: arn:aws:iam::xxx:policy/csr-Developer-Permissions-Boundary
      Path: /my/default/path/
      RoleName: myServerlessRole-${self:service}
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: myPolicyName
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                Resource:
                  - 'Fn::Join':
                    - ':'
                    -
                      - 'arn:aws:logs'
                      - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
                      - Ref: 'AWS::AccountId'
                      - 'log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*'
    
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "s3:*"
                Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::*" #
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "lambda:*"
                Resource: "*"               
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - cloudfront:CreateDistribution
                  - cloudfront:GetDistribution
                  - cloudfront:UpdateDistribution
                  - cloudfront:DeleteDistribution
                  - cloudfront:TagResource
                Resource: "arn:aws:cloudfront:::*"
```

Trying to deploy this gets me the error:

```
Error:
CREATE_FAILED: CustomDashresourceDashexistingDashs3LambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Resource handler returned message: "The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 812c5384-1c26-42c9-bdef-1ce4a59f2be4)" (RequestToken: 9cdbb5af-3bc7-d6bf-384b-5126d1048ccd, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

How can I deploy this lambda triggered by an s3 event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that CustomDashresourceDashexistingDashs3LambdaFunction lambda runs as the `deployementRole` and not under the defined `role` (which is the default role that lambdas run under).  Given the deployment role doesn't normally need to `assumeRole` my deployment role did not have the assumeRole permission.

The fix for this is to ensure that the `sts:assumeRole` trust relationship has been applied to the `deploymentRole` like so:

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
```